# How do I log a value in Pulumi?

Tags: typescript, pulumi

Per [Pulumi's documentation for inputs and outputs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/) I am attempting to `console.log()` a string value of an output.

```
console.log(
  `>>> masterUsername`,
  rdsCluster.masterUsername.apply((v) => `swag${v}swag`)
);
```

returns

```
    >>> masterUsername OutputImpl {
      __pulumiOutput: true,
      resources: [Function (anonymous)],
      allResources: [Function (anonymous)],
      isKnown: Promise { <pending> },
      isSecret: Promise { <pending> },
      promise: [Function (anonymous)],
      toString: [Function (anonymous)],
      toJSON: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
```

I am running `` o.apply(v => `prefix${v}suffix`) `` as specified.

**How can I log a value from Pulumi?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it the other way around:

```
rdsCluster.masterUsername.apply(v =>
  console.log(`>>> masterUsername`, `swag${v}swag`));
```

The callback will run when the output value is resolved and will print the value at that time. In preview, it may not run at all if the value isn't known.

Comment: As some feedback, the term ‘apply’ is not generally used for continuation passing in JavaScript / TS so the name here is confusing. Maybe onComplete would be better. Or change Pulimi to use Promises!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to log the value inside the `apply()`. Here's some example code from an S3 bucket to show you how it'd look:

```
bucket.arn.apply(arn => console.log(arn))
```

It's worth noting that pulumi has its [own logging functions](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/logging/) which will log engine values including the resource:

```
bucket.arn.apply(arn => pulumi.log.info(`bucket arn: ${arn}`, bucket))
```

The result of this is as follows:

```
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (logging-output-dev):
    arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-eb42897

  aws:s3:Bucket (my-bucket):
    bucket arn: arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-eb42897
```

For more information about why you need to run the logging methods *inside* the apply, take a look at [this blog post](https://www.leebriggs.co.uk/blog/2021/05/09/pulumi-apply.html)